# Getting video information from MediaInfo

Tags: bash, shell, video

To get the dimensions of a file, I can do:

```
$ mediainfo '--Inform=Video;%Width%x%Height%' ~/Desktop/lawandorder.mov
1920x1080
```

However, if I give a url instead of a file, it returns None:

```
$ mediainfo '--Inform=Url;%Width%x%Height%' 'http://url/lawandorder.mov'
(none)
```

How would I correctly pass a url to `MediaInfo`?

Comment: Thank you. Your question helped me find an answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/752014/how-can-i-determine-if-a-video-can-be-encoded-successfully-with-hevc-x265-enco

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `curl | head` to partially download the file before running `mediainfo`.

Here's an example of getting the dimensions of a 12 MB file from the web, where only a small portion (less than 10 KB) from the start needs to be downloaded:

```
curl --silent http://www.jhepple.com/support/SampleMovies/MPEG-2.mpg \
  | head --bytes 10K > temp.mpg
mediainfo '--Inform=Video;%Width%x%Height%' temp.mpg
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this, I needed to re-compile from source using '--with-libcurl' option.

```
$ ./CLI_Compile.sh --with-libcurl
$ cd MediaInfo/Project/GNU/CLI
$ make install
```

Then I used this command to get video dimensions via http:

```
$ mediainfo '--Inform=Video;%Width%x%Height%' 'http://url/lawandorder.mov'
```

Note, this took a considerable amount of time to return the results. I'd recommend using `ffmpeg` if the file is not local.